# Design pattern for one page in Typescript

Tags: oop, typescript, design-patterns

I have an application in single page application.
I have also registration and logging outside.

I'd like to know if i should use for login and registration and password recovery:

1.standard singleton pattern with class.

```
export class Register {
    foo(): any {}
}
```

2.or maybe only "export function foo" in Register.ts etc..?

```
export function foo: any {}
```

3.or everything keep in module Registration, module Login?

```
module Publics {
    export module Register {
        export function foo(): any {
            // ...            
        }
    }
    export module Login {
        export function foo(): any {
            // ...            
        }
    }
}
```

It is 1 file additional, PublicCommons.ts with common functions...

Comment: The solution #2. And do not use the keyword `module`, it is not for module but `namespace`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript utopia is found in modules, which keep everything neatly organised without contributing to global scope. In this ideal world, you would have...

regsister.ts

```
export function foo() {

}

//... other registration related code
```

login.ts

```
export function foo() {

}

//... other login related code
```

In this case, you wouldn't need any namespaces (previously known as internal modules) as you've already "done better than namespaces" by using modules (previously known as external modules).

Each of your modules makes its dependencies explicit with import statements, for example:

```
import { foo } from './register';
```

You still have the option to bundle the output into a single file as part of your developer workflow... or you can keep the modules intact at runtime using a module loader. Loading smaller files, when they are needed, with small units of cacheability isn't a bad thing.